# Database architecture for permission lookups

Tags: mysql, database-design, cassandra, permissions, nosql

I have to model a database with Products and Users.

Products has several columns - Price, Weight, Description etc. Each User has permissions to specific rows in Products, and specific cells within those rows.

What is the best way to model the permissions for fast lookups at scale? Assume we can have millions of products and hundreds of thousands of users. And some Product cells can change pretty often.

I have thought of the following:

- NoSql DB with productId, Product cell, UserId, CellPermission.
- Graph DB with Products and Users as nodes and Permissions is the relation.
- MySQL with Products and Users and Permissions tables and do multiple queries and joins

What would give the best performance?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a keyvalue store like redis for faster lookups, with key being UserId and the value, the list of fields and the permissions.

Assuming the fact that, we know well ahead who is the logged on user and the list of fields for the product, all we need to know is the highest privilege the user has for that field. If that can stored in an easy lookup, it would make things better.

Lets assume a Product has 3 Fields

- Field1
- Field2
- Field3 and the permissions are as follows
- UserA can read Field1, Field2 but not Field3
- UserB can only read and update Field1
- administrator can read/update/delete all the fields

then the lookup would look like

KEY  | VALUE  (a dictionary of fields & permissions serialized into json)

1. UserA |                  { "field1": 1, "field2": 1,"field3": 1 }
2. UserB  |             { "field1": 2 }
3. Administrator |          { "field1": 4, "field2": 4,"field3": 4 }

NOTE : Permissions can be stored as bitwise enumeration where 1,2,4 mentioned above represents read, edit and delete permissions.